# Is it possible to apply CSS to an element whose name contains a particular string?

Tags: html, css

I know I can apply CSS styles to an element based on its name:

```
input[name=description] {    
    width: 200px;
}
```

But is it possible to apply CSS styles to elements that contain a particular string in its name?

Imagine several inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="projectDescription"/>
<input type="text" name="themeDescription"/>
<input type="text" name="methodologyDescription"/>
<input type="text" name="somethingElse"/>
etc...
```

So, I just want to apply styles to the inputs whose name contains the word "Description". Can this be done without scripting?

Comment: Below you have correct answer, it's called **attribute selector**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
input[name*="Description"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9mv3pu/)

[**More info**](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

```
[attr] 
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.
[attr=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    and whose value is exactly "value".
[attr~=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, 
    one of which is exactly "value".
[attr|=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr. 
    Its value can be exactly “value” or can begin with “value”
    immediately followed by “-” (U+002D). It can be used for 
    language subcode matches.
[attr^=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    and whose value is prefixed by "value".
[attr$=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    and whose value is suffixed by "value".
[attr*=value]
    Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    and whose value contains at least one occurrence of 
    string "value" as substring.
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Can it be case unsensitive and consider both `description` and `Description`?

Comment: Just FYI @chiapa the difference between the * and the $ as shown in the answer below, is that the $ is if that word is at the end of the string, whereas the * is anywhere within the string ^^.

Comment: Thank you @Callum., I figured that out through testing

Comment: I've added all the options (from MDN)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is

```css
input[name*=Description] {
  width: 200px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="projectDescription" />
<input type="text" name="themeDescription" />
<input type="text" name="methodologyDescription" />
<input type="text" name="somethingElse" />
```

---

> **1. Attribute selectors**
>
> Attribute selectors let you target an element based on its attributes.
>
> You can specify the element’s attribute only, so all the elements that
>   have that attribute — whatever the value — within the HTML will be
>   targeted, or be more specific and target elements that have particular
>   values on their attributes — and this is where attribute selectors
>   show their power.
>
> **There are 6 different types of attribute selectors:**
>
> **[att=value]** - The attribute has to have the exact value specified.
>
> **[att~=value]** - The attribute’s value needs to be a whitespace separated
>   list of words (for example, class=”title featured home”), and one of
>   the words is exactly the specified value.
>
> **[att|=value]** - The attribute’s value is exactly “value” or starts with
>   the word “value” and is immediately followed by “-“, so it would be
>   “value-“.
>
> **[att^=value]** - The attribute’s value starts with the specified value.
>
> **[att$=value]** - The attribute’s value ends with the specified value.
>
> **[att*=value]** - The attribute’s value contains the specified value.

[click here for some more detailed info on atribute selector's](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/17/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

---

As for wanting to select it regardless of the capital the only way I beleive you could do this (without the use of a code other than CSS) would be to just drop the capital from your query so you would have `input[name*=escription]` instead of `input[name*=Description]`

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't answer my question exactly. The string can be in the middle and none of these will affect them then

Comment: Hi Chiapa, '*= means anywhere.' would

Comment: Thanks DCdaz, I know, you added that after my comment

Comment: No I never I added it before your comment but still added it in

Answer (score 0):

You can even ad data if you want. 
input[data-name="themeDescription"] {
    width: 300px;
}

Answer (score -2):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ea3pengv/1/)

```
  input[name*="Description"] {    
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Vicky, thank you for your answer but, have you read the question?